# How to make Web app for Updating title of YouTube video?

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, google-api, access-token

I have a code which updates YouTube title according to views, Thing is it works only in terminal.
It asks for auth token, and after that it updates title, my question is how i can make a Flask app which will take auth token as input and it will pass auth token to the "Title Updater code (YouToob function in my case)".
If i try to hard code the token in "TitleUpdater" then it says "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'authorize'"

**Flask code from where i want to pass auth token:-**

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,flash
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow 
import googleapiclient.discovery 
import googleapiclient.errors
import YouToob
app = Flask(__name__)
run_with_ngrok(app)
auth_link = "Here was massive auth link" 
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def hello():
  return render_template('start.html')

@app.route('/update', methods=['GET','POST'])
def update():
  global auth_link
  if request.method=="POST":
    token = request.form.get("Auth")
    YouToob.YouToob("Tried to pass auth token from here...")
  return render_template('ytb.html',link=auth_link)

app.run()
```

**start.html:-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>VieUpdator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/update">
        <button type="submit">START</button></a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Ytb.html involved in FLASK app:-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>VieUpdator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Go to the link specified and get auth token</p>
    <br>
    <a href="{{ link }}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">auth token</a>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="Auth" placeholder="Enter Authentication token here">
        <button name="Modify">Update</button>      
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Title Updater code which demands for auth token in the terminal:-**

```
import os
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow 
import googleapiclient.discovery 
import googleapiclient.errors

    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"
    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"

    client_secrets_file = "\\secret.json"

    youtube = []
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube.append(googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials))
```

**ERROR Message:-**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "c:\Users\Chris\Desktop\YouTube\VieUpdator.py", line 19, in update
    YouToob.YouToob(token)
  File "c:\Users\Chris\Desktop\YouTube\YouToob.py", line 25, in YouToob
    youtube.append(googleapiclient.discovery.build(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 302, in build
    service = build_from_document(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 585, in build_from_document
    http = _auth.authorized_http(credentials)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_auth.py", line 119, in authorized_http
    return credentials.authorize(build_http())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'authorize'
```

**HERE IS SEQUENCE WISE IMAGES SHOWING WHAT IS HAPPENING:-**

[1: Running the Flask App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgAkx.jpg)

[2: Output of Flask App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWn33.jpg)

[3: Getting Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZNok.jpg)

[4: Passing token to Flask so that YouToob function (title updater) can be called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEamO.jpg)

[5: FrontEnd Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYge3.jpg)

[Actual Error at backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4C54.jpg)

I hope i haven't confused you with my question, it's my first question in stackoverflow.
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: can you show the error and i don't see titleupdater variable in python. you should add action to the form tag `<form action="/update" method="POST">`

Comment: Sorry, let me also include error message also

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('cred.json')
```

I found it in [docs](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#service-account-private-key-files).

Comment: Where can i find 'cred.json' is it the same as 'secret.jason' which i am using?

Comment: follow this [tutorial](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7378726?hl=en) by google to create service account and get the json file.